# Leveraged ETF calculation - dropping below zero?

Tags: black-scholes, etf, leverage

I'm running some simulations with a leveraged ETF to investigate that notorious leveraged-ETF decay effect I keep hearing about. When I put in a typical Black-Scholes lognormal model of returns on the underlying, I run into the following issue:

It is theoretically possible for an ETF to lose half its value in a day. E.g. ITOT can go from a price of 100 dollar to a price of 50 dollars in the next day, for a -50 percent daily return. Now suppose I have a 3x leveraged ETF whose underlying is ITOT. In theory, my return should be 3*(-50)=-150 percent. But this would mean that a 100 dollar investment in the leveraged fund turns into a 50 dollar LIABILITY overnight!! I have not only lost all my money, I now owe 50 dollars!

Do any of you know what would *actually* happen in this scenario? Would the price just drop to zero? Or would it drop to negative 50 dollars? Do the leveraged-ETF prospectuses address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3x leveraged fund that experiences a drop of more than 33% will lose all its money and close down when the value hits 0. Most funds, however, set a lower loss limit, usually around 5%, 10% or 20%, and will try to exit the market if those values are triggered. Of course, it is not that easy to exit efficiently in a day where the market drops that much.

So, usually you will not end up with a liability, but most likely lose your investment or retain a small part of it.

Comment: 33% drop in a day can certainly happen. But the famous Black Monday crash of 1987 was only 23%. So we are talking about rare events.

Comment: I'm not saying anything about the probability of such a loss, just that it can happen, and what will happen in the given case.

Comment: I agree with you 100%